# Stored Prcedure for Create another Table and column from existing database source

Tags: python, mysql

Good afternoon
I want to make a stored procedure that generates auditories tables.

Flow:
If the table exists then add new columns else create the new table same as the original without restrictions

also create another control columns such as User, date, and more, which are detailed in the next SQL code:

```
USE Based;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS TEST;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST(
IN DbName VARCHAR(255),
IN Tablename VARCHAR(255),
IN AuditDb varchar(255)
)
BEGIN

SET @AuditTableName = CONCAT("Aud_",Tablename);
set @TrimAuditTableName =concat("'",@AuditTableName,"'");
set @TrimDbName = concat("'",DbName,"'");
set @TrimTablename =concat("'",Tablename,"'");
set @TrimAuditDb =concat("'",AuditDb,"'");
set @TrimAuditTableName =concat("'",@AuditTableName,"'");

    IF  NOT EXISTS( SELECT NULL 
                FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE table_name ="'"+@AuditTableName+"'" AND table_schema  = "'"+@AuditDb+"'")
               
    THEN
    

 
select "OPCION 1";
    
    SET @SQL = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE " ,AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," AS select * from ",Tablename,";");
    
     prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
    SET @SQL = CONCAT("TRUNCATE TABLE " ,AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName,";");
    
     prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;   
    

    
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AudiEstado VARCHAR(255)");

       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AuditDMLAccion VARCHAR(255)");
       
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AuditUsuario VARCHAR(255)");
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AuditEstacion VARCHAR(255)");
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AuditUpdateColumna VARCHAR(255)");
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
              
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AuditFecha timestamp");
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
    
    ELSE
    
    SELECT "OPCION 2";
       BEGIN
       
            DECLARE bDone INT;
            DECLARE COLUMNA VARCHAR(255);    -- or approriate type
            DECLARE TIPO VARCHAR(255);
            DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
            WHERE table_name = @TrimTablename and table_schema = 'Based' 
            AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name = @TrimAuditTableName and table_schema = @TrimAuditDb )
            ;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET bDone = 1;
        
  OPEN curs;

  SET bDone = 0;
  REPEAT
    FETCH curs INTO COLUMNA, TIPO;

  
       -- here for whatever_transformation_may_be_desired
       
       
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD COLUMN ",COLUMNA," ",TIPO," ;");
        SELECT @SQL;
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
              
   
  UNTIL bDone END REPEAT;

  CLOSE curs;
  
END;  
    END IF;
END; 

//
```

I tried by python but i do not know how to handle in cse of new columns.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

i could achieve the objectives, i share you the final code

```
    USE Based;

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS DDL;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE DDL(
IN DbName VARCHAR(255),
IN Tablename VARCHAR(255),
IN AuditDb varchar(255)
)


BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempoColumnas;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempoColumnas(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    N_Columna varchar(255),
    N_TipoDato varchar(255)
    );
SET @AuditTableName := CONCAT("Aud_",Tablename);
set @TrimAuditTableName :=concat("'",@AuditTableName,"'");
set @TrimDbName := concat("'",DbName,"'");
set @TrimTablename :=concat("'",Tablename,"'");
set @TrimAuditDb := concat("'",AuditDb,"'");
set @TrimAuditTableName := concat("'",@AuditTableName,"'");

CALL sys.table_exists('Based','Categorias',  @table_type); 
SELECT @table_type;

    IF  (@table_type <> 'BASE TABLE')
               
    THEN
    

 
select "OPCION 1";
    
    SET @SQL = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE " ,AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," AS select * from ",Tablename,";");
    
     prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
    SET @SQL = CONCAT("TRUNCATE TABLE " ,AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName,";");
    
     prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;   
    
    #ESTA BLOQUE LISTO
    
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AudiEstado VARCHAR(255)");

       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AuditDMLAccion VARCHAR(255)");
       
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AuditUsuario VARCHAR(255)");
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AuditEstacion VARCHAR(255)");
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AuditUpdateColumna VARCHAR(255)");
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
              
       SET @SQL = CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName," ADD AuditFecha timestamp");
       prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
    
    ELSE
       SELECT "OPCION 2";
    
    
    set @sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO TempoColumnas (N_Columna,N_TipoDato) SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns 
            WHERE table_name = ",@TrimTablename," and table_schema = 'Based' 
            AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN (SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns WHERE table_name =", @TrimAuditTableName," and table_schema = ",@TrimAuditDb,")
        ;");
            
    prepare stmt1 FROM @SQL;
       EXECUTE stmt1;
       DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
       
       BEGIN
    
       
              
            DECLARE bDone INT;
            DECLARE V_COLUMNA VARCHAR(255);    -- or approriate type
            DECLARE V_TIPO VARCHAR(255);      
             DECLARE var_final INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
            DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  SELECT N_Columna,N_TipoDato FROM TempoColumnas;
            #DECLARE curs CURSOR FOR  SELECT Columna, TipoDato FROM TempoColumnas;
            DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET var_final = 1;

        
  OPEN curs;
bucle: LOOP
    FETCH curs INTO V_COLUMNA,V_TIPO;

    IF var_final = 1 THEN
    LEAVE bucle;
    END IF;
    select V_COLUMNA;  
       -- here for whatever_transformation_may_be_desired
       
    SET @ddl=CONCAT("ALTER TABLE ",AuditDb,".",@AuditTableName,
            " ADD COLUMN ",V_COLUMNA," ",V_TIPO,";");
        SELECT @ddl;
        PREPARE stmt FROM @ddl;
        EXECUTE stmt;
       #
       
  END LOOP bucle;

  CLOSE curs;
  
END;  
    END IF;
END; 

//
/*
USE Based;
SELECT * FROM Categorias;
ALTER TABLE Categorias add column Nueva03 varchar(100);
*/

USE Based;
CALL DDL("Based","Categorias","AudiDb");
```